# App : Cake change to own

Tags: php, cakephp, cron

i have not that much of idea regarding cakephp v2.8.0.I install cakephp through command through  terminal and when i type "cake" i get below statement

### > Welcome to CakePHP v2.8.0 Console

App : Cake

### Path: /usr/share/php/Cake/

Current Paths:

-app: Cake
 -working: /usr/share/php/Cake
 -root: /usr/share/php
 -core: /usr/share/php

Changing Paths:

Your working path should be the same as your application path. To change your path use the '-app' param.
Example: -app relative/path/to/myapp or -app /absolute/path/to/myapp

Available Shells:

> I want to change " App : Cake " to "App : my_app".
>   Please help

Comment: A kitten dies everytime you install a CakePHP version prior to 3.0...

Answer (score 0):

check this to complete your installation: [CakePHP Shells, Tasks & Console Tools](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html)